# Android listview with array adapter......Change color of text in listview on click on button 1 and different color of text on click on button2

Tags: android

How can I change the text in `listview` with `color1` if `button1` is clicked and `color2` if `button2` is clicked?

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(),R.layout.text2);

button1.setOnClickListener()
{
    listview.add("item1");
}
button2.setOnClickistnere()
{
    listview.add("item2");
}
```

`item1` should be of `color1` and `item2` of `color2`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to Buttons's OnClickListner()

change the COLOR1 and COLOR2 etc with "Color codes"

For Button 1:

```
    Button1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) { 
        listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("COLOR1"))
      }
    }
);
```

For Button 2:

```
    Button1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) { 
        listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("COLOR2"))
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: this changes the background color of the listview. I want to have item 1 in color 1 and with this item 2 in color 2

Comment: I think you are asking that how to change the TEXT-color  of items in the listview ?

Comment: As i m assuming that you have a Listview's custom layout for an item...?

Comment: Assume that there is an edit text and two buttons. Now when you type text in edittext and press button1 the text should appear in color1 and if you press button2 then the text should appear in color2 and the earlier text should remain unchanged wrt color

Comment: I think best way you can handle this is by making 2 custom-listview-layout  for each of the button ...if button1 is clicked a listitem generates from custom-listview-layout 1 and other accordingly ...you can refer to this link to do this ...http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html

Comment: Using this above way your listview can be better customized  or you can do the same by accessing the listview's edittext attributes ...

Answer (score 0):

**You can use onItemClickListner() method to select the item and set the color based on selection. Pick the color codes from array and set the color to list object background.**

```
String colorList[] = {"#112211", "#c0c0c0", "#121111"};

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{

      @Override 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3){ 
        lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorList[position]))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create res/color/button_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This layout XML will apply the color list to a View:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
```

And if you want to apply State Color Dynamically then

```
ColorStateList myColorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                    new int[][]{
                            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, //1
                            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_focused}, //2
                            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected, android.R.attr.state_pressed} //3
                    },
                    new int[] {
                        Color.RED, //1
                        Color.WHITE, //2
                        Color.BLUE //3
                    }
                );
            title_txt.setTextColor(myColorStateList);
```

Comment: you can also refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html and accept this as an answer if it helped or cleared your concept